# Cisco ASA 5200 LAN Traffic not getting out

Tags: nat, cisco-asa, ios

I have a remote client with an ASA 5200. They are going to get fiber, but for now are using their building's internet. The ASA config is below (edited for anonymity). It is able to ping the gateway (10.133.30.177), as well as 8.8.8.8 and other IPs. When attached to the 0/2 interface, a machine gets an IP in the 192.168.220.0/24 and can ping 192.168.220.1, but no further (not even 10.144.30.190). I've run "packet-tracer input inside icmp 192.168.220.102 8 0 8.8.8.8 detailed"

Here is my config:

```
ASA Version 8.3(2)
!
hostname NY-ASA5200
names
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 shutdown
 nameif FIBER
 security-level 0
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif&nbsp;INET
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.144.30.190 255.255.255.240
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 nameif INSIDE
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.220.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
dns server-group DefaultDNS
object network inside-subnet
 subnet 192.168.220.0 255.255.255.0
object network outside
 host 10.144.30.190
access-list inside_out_acl extended permit ip any any
access-list inside_out_acl extended permit icmp any any
pager lines 24
mtu FIBER 1500
mtu INET 1500
mtu INSIDE 1500
no failover
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
!
object network inside-subnet
 nat (INSIDE,INET) dynamic interface
route Regis 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.144.30.177 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
sla monitor 123
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 8.8.8.8 interface FIBER
 num-packets 4
 frequency 15
sla monitor schedule 123 life forever start-time now
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
!
track 1 rtr 123 reachability
telnet 192.168.220.0 255.255.255.0 INSIDE
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd address 192.168.220.100-192.168.220.150 INSIDE
dhcpd enable INSIDE
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ssl encryption aes256-sha1
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
 message-length maximum client auto
 message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
 inspect dns preset_dns_map
 inspect ftp
 inspect h323 h225
 inspect h323 ras
 inspect ip-options
 inspect netbios
 inspect rsh
 inspect rtsp
 inspect skinny
 inspect esmtp
 inspect sqlnet
 inspect sunrpc
 inspect tftp
 inspect sip
 inspect xdmcp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
 no active
 destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
 destination address email callhome@cisco.com
 destination transport-method http
 subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
 subscribe-to-alert-group environment
 subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
 subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
 subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:1bf8d353c86639077a01cf3ee2762a42
: end
```

Here is the building's internet info:

```
Vlan ID: 33
Public IPs: N/A
Dynamic IPs: 10.144.30.178-10.144.30.189
Local Network: 10.144.30.176/28
Netmask: 255.255.255.240
Gateway IP: 10.144.30.177
DNS1: 66.194.134.66
DNS2: 66.194.134.65
Static IPs: 10.144.30.190
DHCP Enabled: Yes
Address Translations: N/A
Bandwidth Type: Shared
```

Finally, here's the packet-tracer output:

```
Phase: 1
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: input
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
in 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 INET

Phase: 2
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
 Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
 in id=0x738aa2e8, priority=0, domain=inspect-ip-options, deny=true
 hits=564, user_data=0x0, cs_id=0x0, reverse, flags=0x0, protocol=0
 src ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0
 dst ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0, dscp=0x0
 input_ifc=INSIDE, output_ifc=any

Phase: 3
Type: INSPECT
Subtype: np-inspect
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
 Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
 in id=0x738a9f50, priority=66, domain=inspect-icmp-error, deny=false
 hits=280, user_data=0x738a9e38, cs_id=0x0, use_real_addr, flags=0x0, protocol=1
 src ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0
 dst ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0, dscp=0x0
 input_ifc=INSIDE, output_ifc=any

Phase: 4
Type: NAT
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
object network inside-subnet
 nat (INSIDE,INET) dynamic interface
Additional Information:
Dynamic translate 192.168.220.102/0 to 10.144.30.190/16722
 Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
 in id=0x735116e0, priority=6, domain=nat, deny=false
 hits=215, user_data=0x6c7766e0, cs_id=0x0, use_real_addr, flags=0x0, protocol=0
 src ip/id=192.168.220.0, mask=255.255.255.0, port=0
 dst ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0, dscp=0x0
 input_ifc=INSIDE, output_ifc=INET

Phase: 5
Type: FLOW-CREATION
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
New flow created with id 592, packet dispatched to next module
Module information for forward flow ...
snp_fp_tracer_drop
snp_fp_inspect_ip_options
snp_fp_translate
snp_fp_adjacency
snp_fp_fragment
snp_ifc_stat

Module information for reverse flow ...

Result:
input-interface: INSIDE
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: INET
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: allow
```

Answer (score 0):

To ping "through" the ASA you should enable the icmp inspection under `policy-map global_policy` - `class inspection_default` :

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11124056/why-enable-icmp-inspection-will-allow-icmp-traffic-pass-asa
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/i2.html#wp1735986

I can't see any `access-group` entry in your configuration, inside_out_acl isn't bound to any interface and I think it will never match. You can check the access list hit count with `show access-list` while pinging.

However, ip/icmp traffic should be allowed because of the security levels assigned to the interfaces.